# Add zero digit to number with NumberFormatter

Tags: swift, foundation, numberformatter

I have a string

```
let str = "2.1"
```

I want to cast it in Double and always have 2 digits after the separator like that :

```
let double = 2.10
```

So what I do is :

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.decimalSeparator = "."
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

let myDoubleValue = formatter.number(from: str)?.doubleValue
```

And the output is still with only 1 fraction digit : `2.1`

why ?

Comment: `2.1` and `2.10` are identical values.   minimumFractionDigits is only relevant when converting a number to a *string* with the decimal representation.

Comment: If you care about the rightmost `0` you shouldn't "cast" it to double, you should keep it as a String

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you mean is:

```
let str = "2.1"
if let double = Double(str) as? NSNumber {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.decimalSeparator = "."
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    if let myNewStringValue = formatter.string(from: double) {
        print(myNewStringValue) // 2.10
    }
}
```

Comment: ok but I want a double so you are making : string > double > string > double. I would think there is a better way

Comment: @user3722523 If you want a `Double`, you can't have a 0 at the end - it's mathematically meaningless, only relevant as part of the string representation. What exactly are you trying to do where you need to display the 0 but also keep it a `Double` for some reason?

Comment: the user enter 1.8 in the textField of my tableView (so its a string). Then the value is registered in a realm database as a double. Then the value is displayed on a PDF invoice. And I don't to have a number with 1 fraction digit and another with 2 fraction digits on the same invoice.

Comment: There is no need to create a `NSNumber` object. Just use `Formatter`s method `string(for: Any)` and pass your `Double` to it.  `if let double = Double(str) {`
   
   `if let myNewStringValue = formatter.string(for: double) {`

Comment: @user3722523 But you don't need it to be a `Double` when you display it on the PDF, do you? Convert it and add the 0 when you build the PDF, or when you pass the data to whatever code handles that.

Comment: yes I think I will add a 0 just before displaying the value. But I wanted to know if there was a solution with NumberFormatter that is design to ... format number...

Comment: @user3722523 Listen closely. There is no such thing as formatting a number. You cannot "see" a number. There is nothing to format. It is just a quantity. What you format is a _string_ — a visible _representation_ of a number. Two things are two things; two is a _fact_. "2" is a way of _writing_ and _showing_ how many things there are. "2.10" is a _string_, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a double with trailing 0's, it will truncate.

If you're simply displaying the value, keep it as a string.
If you're performing calculations, what difference would the 0's make?